# How does increased fluid velocity give rise to low fluid pressure at a point?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

Pressure difference is inversely proportional to velocity. But how is it valid at a point?

Can you also include the example when we squeeze a pipe in which water is flowing, the velocity increases? And the pressure too increases, right?

Comment: Your two statements are contradictory pressure is inversely proportional to velocity states a different meaning . In 2nd statement you support the fact that pressure increses with increasing velocity

Comment: First statement I meant about pressure difference between 2 things. In the second statement, I asked if the pressure will also increase when you squeeze a water flowing tube (as you apply pressure the pressure inside must also increase right). But acc to your answer the pressure is inversely proportional to velocity. Can you justify please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two equations are sufficient to prove this

Firstly equation of continuity
A1v1=A2v2  ........A~area  v~ velocity

Since you press the pipe its area decreases thereby velocity increases

---

Next is bernoullis theorum according to which

*h$\rho$g +1/2$\rho$ $v^2$+ $P1$= constant*

Since this sum is constant if one increases other has to decrease. If at a point velocity increases than other point then pressure has to decrease as compared to the other point to ensure the sum remains constant